# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Razor Datatables Ajax not show JSon data

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor, datatables

I have a page with a table, with one column, using DataTables; i load data with an ajax call.

Data are returned to the page but table show no row. I don't have any error show on browser.

This is my HTML with JQuery:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="DetailsTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0"</table>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(function () {

   $('#DetailsTable').DataTable({               
       "responsive": true,
       "processing": true,
       "serverSide": true,               
       "ajax": {
           "url": "/Index?handler=Table",
           "type": "GET",
           "dataSrc": "",
           "dataType": "json"
       },
       "columnDefs": [
           { "targets": "detail_ID", visible: true }
       ],
       "columns": [
           { "data": "detail_ID" }]
   });
});
</script>
```

This is my method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableAsync()
{
   wItem = await _detailRepo.Finddetail(CancellationToken.None);

   string NewtonJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wItem);
   return Content(NewtonJSON);

}
```

and this is reurned JSON:

```
{
   "detail_ID": 7,
   "detail_GUID": "685b8741-fe22-460a-bb76-7ecd9c320172"
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you don't need to convert your result to json - web api handles that for you in c#:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableAsync()
{
   var wItem = await _detailRepo.Finddetail(CancellationToken.None);

   //string NewtonJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wItem);
   return Content(wItem );

}
```

I think you may want to change the return type to OK:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableAsync()
{
   var wItem = await _detailRepo.Finddetail(CancellationToken.None);
   return Ok(wItem );

}
```

And return a list (to fit into the table)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableAsync()
{
   var wItem = await _detailRepo.Finddetail(CancellationToken.None);
   return Ok(new List<object> {wItem} );

}
```

I believe this should return something like:

```
[{
   "detail_ID": 7,
   "detail_GUID": "685b8741-fe22-460a-bb76-7ecd9c320172"
}]
```

Which should be more compatible with tables

You may have to also change the "ajax" part of the ajax call:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": "/Index?handler=Table",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "application/json"
}
```

Update: Looks like you need to return specific object looking at the example [Here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

So you need to make your object look like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "detail_ID": 7,
        "detail_GUID": "685b8741-fe22-460a-bb76-7ecd9c320172"
    }]
}
```

The easiest way to do this is probably going to be to update your server-side do something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableAsync()
{
   var wItem = await _detailRepo.Finddetail(CancellationToken.None);
   return Ok(new { data = new List<object> {wItem} });

}
```

I believe there is a .Net nuget package for data table that will give you a more appropriate type to return

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, doesn't work. I have change my method with _"return new OkObjectResult(new List<object> { wItem });"_ and _"dataType": "application/json"_ but now i have the error "DataTables warning: table id=DetailsTable - Invalid JSON". This is the returned JSON:[{"detail_ID":7,"detail_GUID":"685b8741-fe22-460a-bb76-7ecd9c320172"}]

Comment: Thanks Mark, you save my time. It work. I will find also that, if you have a nested object, you can retrive the column with ""dataSrc": "data.0.NeastedDetails"".

Comment: It's what were here for :)